# Trouble with liking and like.php

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am trying to optimize some things for my website for a company that I own. The name of the company was changed a few weeks ago. The problem is that when someone hits the "like" button on our website, facebook shows that the user liked the old company name. The website is www.puzzlecreatives.com. THe old name was platinum marketing. The problem seems to be located in "like.php" I cannot find where this file is at anywhere on our server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`like.php` is on Facebook's server, that's not actually where the problem lies. The problem is that your "facebook application" is what's attached to the button, and that's still associated with the old company name.

Go [here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps), sign into your company Facebook account and change the details.